# Why does paypal give us 401 error on REST API

Tags: rest, api, paypal

Im here because we need your assistance. What is going on...

We have website where we are using paypal as payment method. We integrated paypal with REST API. In sandbox everything worked just fine.

Then we decided to go to production mode. On the front end everythings looks fine.

1. You are on the website and go to checkout with paypal.
2. Site redirects you to paypal url for payment. You login or fill info and click button "pay"
3. You get redirected back on the website to the success page.

Seems like everything is ok but no funds are transferred and paypal does not send informational email about payment. Payment just doesnt happend...

In log we can see this error:

> 2018-10-14 14-09-49] MetisFW\PayPal\PayPalException: Got Http response code 401 when accessing https://api.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token.Data: {"error":"invalid_client","error_description":"Client Authentication failed"} #401 in /data/cust/feel4it/www.ourdomain.com/vendor/metisfw/paypal/src/MetisFW/PayPal/Payment/BasePaymentOperation.php:145 caused by PayPal\Exception\PayPalConnectionException: Got Http response code 401 when accessing https://api.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token. #401 in /data/cust/feel4it/www.ourdomain.com/vendor/paypal/rest-api-sdk-php/lib/PayPal/Core/PayPalHttpConnection.php:180 @ https://www.ourdomain.com/checkout/summary @@ exception--2018-10-14--14-09--55ea9e45a2.html

We are in the dead end. We tried everything and checked our creditials like 1000x times. Everything seems to be set right but still not working :(

Do you have experiences with this? Can you help me?

Thank you very much for your time. I really appreciate that.

Martin
Vizzio Group

Comment: Did you change client id and secret from sandbox to production in your application?

Comment: Yes we did. I am in communication with paypal support. It was first thing they asked. After few messages they came up with this:
-----
Your integration does the steps right, but there is one missing.

That is the DoExpressCheckoutPayment Request.

DoExpressCheckout needs to be done in your site upon return (after pressing on "continue")

At the moment, your integration redirects to your site but there is no option to finish the payment on your site.

That's why no payments are showing in your account, because there are non.
-----
Do you have any clue what they are talking about?